# calling parallel react queries dynamically, but data is returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-query

i am trying to call an employee data for a number empCode available in an array, by using useQueries hook from react-query.

i have applied axiosinstance to call in function getEmployeeData where i am returning res.data. then i applied useQueries hook for dynamic api call, api call is successful when i run console.log(res.data) the result is showing in console.

when i tired to get the data form empQueries as it return an array of result data in react.useEffect the data is retuning undefined there.

```
const getEmployeeData = async (empCode: string) => {
let URL = `/api/hcm/employee/getempautofill?Rows=100&PageNo=1&EmpCode=${empCode}`;
const TOKEN = localStorage.getItem("token");

axiosInstance({
  method: "get",
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_HRMS_API_URL,
  url: URL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
    "api-version": "V1.0",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US",
  },
})
  .then((res: any) => {
    if (res.data.Status !== false) {
      console.log("returned emp data", res.data); 
      return res.data;
    }
  })
  .catch((err: any) => {
    console.log("error employee data", err);
  });
```

};

this is the array of empCode

```
const empData = ["EMP4991", "EMP4992"];
```

this is the useQueries funtion

```
  const empQueries = useQueries(
//todo check multiple api call
empData.map((emp) => {
  return {
    queryKey: ["emp", emp],
    queryFn: () => getEmployeeData(emp),
  };
 })
);

  React.useEffect(() => {
  debugger;
  empQueries
   .filter((query) => query.isSuccess)
   .map((query) => console.log("data is: ", query.data)); // this return undefined but 
         // i want here to return the res.data
  }, [empQueries]);
```

help me, am i doiong something wrong is there any syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getEmployeeData` function is marked as `async` but `axioInstance` doesn't make use of `await`. You should try something like:

```
const getEmployeeData = async (empCode: string) => {
    let URL = `/api/hcm/employee/getempautofill?Rows=100&PageNo=1&EmpCode=${empCode}`;
    const TOKEN = localStorage.getItem('token');

    try {
        const res = await axiosInstance({
            method: 'get',
            baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_HRMS_API_URL,
            url: URL,
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
                'api-version': 'V1.0',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US'
            }
        });
        if (res.data.Status !== false) {
            return res.data;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error employee data', err);
    }
};
```

Also, please make sure `res.data.Status` actually returns `true` or even the change above won't resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, now it's returning the data values